# Contour Plot of a matrix of Values in xy plane

Tags: graph, octave, contour

this is my first question and sorry if it is inappropriate.

I have a matrix of values that are measures taken in a plane, every 50 cm, on the two axis: i.e. from -3 meters to 3 meters in latitude and from -3 m to 3 m in longitude.
This results in a matrix of 13 rows and 13 column.

I would like to plot the isolines through the contour function.

Let's say M is the matrix read from file.

***contour(M):*** makes the calculations and draw the result, but I do not know how to scale on the axis I want.

In other words, from -3 to 3 :0.5 on x and -3 to 3 :0.5 on y

It's my first attempt to Octave, so sorry if my question is so boring.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE2eW.png)

Thank you for your rapid answer and sorry my delay in reply.

I made some progress thanks to your feedback; now I would like to round the clabel of contour to two digits after decimal points, but I do not success. enter image description here

I try with:

format bank; at the beginning, or:

I=contour(X,Y,K); Y=round(I);

I know it is a dumb question, but any suggestion?

Thank you again.

Comment: Can you improve your question by adding some piece of code to see your current implementation?

Answer (score 0):

The function [`contour`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/contour.html) accepts two more parameters to define the axes:

```
% generate some bogus values
M = rand(13, 13); for k=2:3; M = conv2(M, ones(k)/k^2, 'same'); end

% set up axes
u = linspace(-3, 3, size(M, 1));
v = linspace(-3, 3, size(M, 2)); 
contour(u, v, M);

% if it's possibly an uneven grid, use full matrices:
[U, V] = meshgrid(u, v);
contour(U, V, M);
```

[image]